# Multi Insert in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to make multiple insert in my database table with a FK, but only enter one line of records, it could be I do not count the `$count`. Here my code

Model

```
public function create($table,$data)
    {
    $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
     return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Controller

```
public function save($id)
    {
    $id_form = $id;
    $id_interversion = $this->model->create('mytable1',$data);
        $Inicio = $_POST['Inicio'];
        $Termino = $_POST['Termino'];
        $id_tecnico = $_POST['id_tecnico'];
        $count = count($_POST['id_tecnico']);
        $data2 =array();
                for ($i=0; $i <$count; $i++) {
                    $data2 = array(
                             'id_tecnico'=>$id_tecnico[$i],
                             'horaInicio'=>$Inicio[$i],
                             'Termino'=>$Termino[$i]
                     );
                 $this->model->create('mytable2',$data2);

                }


}
```

view

```
<?php echo form_open("controller/save/{$data->id}"); ?>
      <?php for ($i=0; $i <2; $i++) { ?>
        <input type="text" name="id_tecnico[]"  value="" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" name="Inicio[]"  value="" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" name="Termino[]"  value="" class="form-control">
       <?php } ?>

       <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I hope I explained well greetings

Comment: print_r($_POST['id_tecnico']);exit; and add output to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `insert_batch` like this :

```
public function save($id = NULL)
{
    $id_form = $id;
    //$id_interversion = $this->model->create('mytable1',$data);
    $id_interversion = 12; // a custom id
    $Inicio = $this->input->post('Inicio');
    $Termino = $this->input->post('Termino');
    $id_tecnico = $this->input->post('id_tecnico');
    foreach ($id_tecnico as $key => $item) 
    {
        $insert_data[] = array(
                'id_interversion' => $id_interversion,
                'id_tecnico'=> $item,
                'horaInicio'=> $Inicio[$key],
                'Termino'=> $Termino[$key]
              );
    }
    //print_r($insert_data);die;
    $this->db->insert_batch('mytable2',$insert_data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the insert values into one array and use codeigniter insert_batch method.

Heres a useful documentation
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html